# Listview in Surfaceview created programmatically?

Tags: android, android-listview, surfaceview

I m creating one game application. In which i have created surfaceview using classname extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback. I have surfaceview of full screen. i write dynamically text (word) on right side of surfaceview using canvas.drawtext(). but now the problem is , if text is more then screen height i want to show like listview. so i can scroll and see that words. so is this posible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listview you need your view scrollable. so i would suggest creating text under scroll view.